# jQuery Datatables - How to insert a div between the toolbar and the table?

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

How can I insert a div class="row" between the tool bar and the table itself? *Where the arrow line is in the below image.*

Thank you!

[image: div row where the arrow line is]

Comment: Are you asking how to do this dynamically, or before you open the page?

Comment: Thank you for helping me. Not sure how to answer that question since the table and tool bar are dynamically generated. The new row itself is static. The toolbar is a div class="row'. I just need another row under that one. Hope that makes sense... Thanks again.

Comment: Can you post the HTML that you start with?

Comment: Unfortunately the table itself is obfuscated beyond recognition in an Angular dataTableDirective.js that utilizes this plugin - https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html. But the rendered HTML is similar to what can be found in the first example on that demo page.

Comment: Something like this. 
`<div class="datatables_wrapper">
     <div class="row">toolbar</div>
     <div class="row">inserted new row</div>
     <table></table>
</div>`

Comment: I'm not talking about the rendered HTML code.  I'm talking about the HTML code that is on your HTML page, prior to opening it.  What does that look like, and will you please edit your post and put it in there?

Answer (score 2):

I reckon you can accomplish this using the JQuery insertAfter method.  http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/

First, use a selector for your toolbar and then use the function insertAfter after that.

Sample Html:

```
<div id="toolbar" > Your stuff here </div>

<table id="yourTable">...</table>
```

Sample Jquery code:

```
$("#toolbar").insertAfter("<div class='row'></div>");
```

Comment: Since it isn't always straightforward to figure out which elements before the table are in the toolbar itself - in fact, by default there's not a single `div` or other container element for the toolbar - it's probably better to target the table itself and use `insertBefore`.

Comment: @tmpearce DataTables adds several divs before the table, so that could be a problem as well.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. Could we use a CSS selector such as :nth-last-child?

Comment: Using a selector like that should be possible... I suggest you try using a browser's developer tools feature (F12) to identify which object in the DOM to either append to or insert after. That should help guide you on what to use in your Jquery selector. Good luck!!

Comment: Just looked at the example on https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html, why not try insertAfter after the </thead> element? Unless you have extra divs in the mix that aren't shown on this example.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`dom`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) option to set the placement and then [`initComplete`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete) option to set the content like this:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "dom": "lfr<'#extra'>tip",
    "initComplete": function(settings, json) {
        $("#extra").text("Hello World")
    }
});
```

Working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/tx9wtzss/). Hope that helps.

Comment: This will Add "Hello World" right next to search box, But as per the question, it needs to come below line of search box!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small improvement on [annoyingmouse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/592058/annoyingmouse)'s answer

Instead of

> $("#extra").text("Hello World")

Try using

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "dom": "lfr<'#extra'>tip",
    "initComplete": function(settings, json) {
        $("#extra").html($("#extraDiv"))
    }
});
```

So you can write the div into your html page so its far more readable:

```
//↑ rest of page that way
<div id="extraDiv" style="hidden">
 <span>Hello world</span>
</div>
```

Comment: When i tried this the "Hello World" is appearing right next to search box, but i would need it a line below the search box also the requirement in the question is also same

Answer (score 0):

Have your div HTML somewhere, I have put it just above datatable table tag

HTML :

```
//Div To insert

    <div id="divToInsert" >
    </div>

//Datatable table  

    <table id="Grid" class="dataTable table table-striped table-bordered " style="width: 100% !important">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>        
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>   
    </table>
```

Javascript :

//initialise jquery datatable

```
$('#Grid').DataTable({....});
```

//Insert Div just above the datatable

```
  $("#divToInsert").insertBefore($("#Grid"));
```

Note: I wanted to put some controls inside div and display it just above the grid and below search control.After inserting div using above code I had to use bootstrap "row" class inside div to display the controls properly.